# MPLABX XC16 unable to resolve built-in identifier __builtin_dmaoffset

Tags: c, warnings, built-in, microchip, mplab

Im trying to do some basic ECAN sending using a dsPIC33FJ128GP802 and its built in DMA. The problem that im facing is that all the code examples in the documentation use the built in function `__builtin_dmaoffset()` to set the DMA onset buffer register `DMA1STA` but my compiler keeps telling me:

```
unable to resolve built-in identifier __builtin_dmaoffse
```

The code im using is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>

#include <ADCConfig.h>
#include <ECANConfig.h>

int main(void) {

    oscConfig();

    initADC1();
    initDMA0();

    initECAN1();
    initDMA1();
    initDMA2();

    ... 

    unsigned int ecan1MsgBuf[32][8] __attribute__((space(dma)));
    DMA1STA=__builtin_dmaoffset(ecan1MsgBuf);

    ...
}
```

How do I get the built in function to work?

Comment: That compiler is really really bad. My suggestion: try another compiler if you can

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try that, do you have any suggestions for which compiler might be good ?

Comment: No idea on that, I wouldn't even use a PIC. STM32 or AVR are great. But you can Google that. Anything you find will be better than MPLAB/XC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

__builtin_dmaoffset() need to know the real address in order to calculate the DMA offset value.
Try as follows-

```
#define MSG_BUF_LENGTH 32

int main(void) {
    ....

    unsigned int ecan1MsgBuf[32][8] __attribute__((space(dma),aligned(MSG_BUF_LENGTH*16)));
    DMA1STA=__builtin_dmaoffset(ecan1MsgBuf);

    ....
    }
```

Comment: Your code still gives me the exact same error: `Unable to resolve built-in identifier __builtin_dmaoffset`

Comment: Can you try modifying as ```DMA1STA=__builtin_dmaoffset(&ecan1MsgBuf);```

Comment: Still nothing changing. But maybe this helps, when I try to compile which the error it tells me `Argument to __builtin_dmaoffset()  is not the address`

Comment: Oh I just saw that before the error that we are discussing is thrown the compiler tells me `warning: ignoring space attribute applied to automatic ecan1MsgBuf`, and its showing this warning on this line of code `unsigned int ecan1MsgBuf[32][8] __attribute__((space(dma),aligned(MSG_BUF_LENGTH*16)));` maybe that is helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are trying to pass a 2-array as the argument. Try creating a union that includes your array and sending this to the builtin. I believe that the builtin is implemented as a macro that extracts the address of the parameter and this could cause problems if it's not a simple scalar variable.

I've also used the eds attribute with success on a dsPIC33E processor.

```
typedef union
{
   uint16_t   u16Dummy;
   uint16_t   ecan1MsgBuf[32][8];
} CAN_TYPE;

CAN_TYPE   __attribute__((eds, space(dma), aligned(MSG_BUF_LENGTH*16))) Data;

DMA1STA = __builtin_dmaoffset(Data.u16Dummy);
```